# How do I get a flexbox to have a center fixed and a bottom fixed children together?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am trying to get a layout of the following kind via flexbox.

```
|                      |
|                      |
| CENTER FIXED ELEMENT |
|                      |
| BOTTOM FIXED ELEMENT |
```

This is my rough flexbox CSS.

```
.wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.bottom-element {
    align-self:flex-end;
}
```

The idea behind is that anything inside `wrapper` would get center aligned and `.bottom-element` would align itself to the bottom of the box.

This however doesn't work as expected and **bottom element** appears right after the **center element**.

Any other way this could be solved? or a silly something I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 1:

Center 'middle' div vertically of the whole 'wrapper'.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.middle,
.bottom {
  background: aqua;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

#### Update 2:

Center 'middle' div vertically within the available space of 'wrapper' minus 'bottom'.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.middle,
.bottom {
  background: aqua;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

#### Previous answer:

The idea is creating an empty placeholder for the top element with CSS pseudo content, and then just use `flex-direction: column;` + `justify-content: space-between;` to align all the 3 elements vertically.

**Note:** the middle div might not be absolutely in the middle when comes to multiple lines of text in the flex items.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper:before {
  content: "\00A0";
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>middle</div>
  <div>bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  height: 10em; 
}
.third {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.first{
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="second">Second</div>
  <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```