# How to center vertically a specific child using flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent block `id="parent"` with some child elements. One of them `id="child3"` I need to center it vertically by parent height.

I tried:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
}

#child3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">1</div>
  <div id="child2">2</div>
  <div id="child3">3</div>
</div>
```

Element  1 should be always on top

Comment: You mean that `child3` has to be in the center and the others above it?

Comment: Yes, centered above others and by  parent height

Comment: There is no setting in flexbox to do that. - Probable Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455207/how-do-i-get-a-flexbox-to-have-a-center-fixed-and-a-bottom-fixed-children-togeth

Comment: This is not duplicate, I need center only #child3 {}

Comment: I think it should be position: absolute; top: 50%  - height if text

Comment: to center a flex child, use margin:auto; (both) mind the flex-direction : vertical is margin: auto 0 ; for row and horizontal for a column , margin: 0 auto; is horizontal for a row and vertical for a column. margin can take 4 values, play with it to push your element to center,righ,top,bottom,left ....

Comment: It **is** a duplicate since you can't center `child3` without affecting the other elements. Absolute position will remove it from the flow completely and flexbox will take the other elements into account so you can't center it that way either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with flexbox, you can do that:

only the child-3 will be vertically centered.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.child-3 {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class="child-1">1</div>
  <div class="child-2">2</div>
  <div class="child-3">3</div>
</div>
```