# Moving first item of flex box independently to top of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to move the Case Code Element to the top right of the screen but it is stuck inside of the flexbox and I cant seem to figure out how to move it independently. The display flex is being added to the .sidenav in javascript. `position: absolute` doesn't seem to work?

Image of what I've currently got:

[image: Image of what ive currently got]

```js
function openNav() {
  console.log("opennav");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "flex";
}

function closeNav() {
  console.log("closenav");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.sidenav .action-object {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.sidenav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 120;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*padding-top: 60px;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>-->
  <h1 class="sideNavCaseCode">Case Code</h1>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="home" onclick="closeNav()">Home</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="search" onclick="closeNav()">Search</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="evidence" onclick="closeNav()">People</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="people" onclick="closeNav()">Evidence</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="tools" onclick="closeNav()">Tools</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="questions" onclick="closeNav()">Questions</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please Share your code completely . . .

Comment: This is everything on this page, rest is irrelavant no?

Comment: Yeah I know! But that looked kinda incomplete. So, felt something bad . . .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455207/how-do-i-get-a-flexbox-to-have-a-center-fixed-and-a-bottom-fixed-children-togeth

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-bottom to auto. there are two ways to do it that i know of u can have different class name for the certain object or you can first child pseudo element if you have the same class name

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { margin: 0 } h1 { margin: 0 }

.sidenav {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100vh;
}

.sideNavCaseCode {
  margin-bottom:auto;
}

.action-object {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  display: block;
  color: currentColor;
  background: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin:1px
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>-->
  <h1 class="sideNavCaseCode">Case Code</h1>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="home" onclick="closeNav()">Home</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="search" onclick="closeNav()">Search</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="evidence" onclick="closeNav()">People</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="people" onclick="closeNav()">Evidence</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="tools" onclick="closeNav()">Tools</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="questions" onclick="closeNav()">Questions</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this. seems work.

```
.sideNavCaseCode {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```js
function openNav() {
  console.log("opennav");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "flex";
}

function closeNav() {
  console.log("closenav");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.sidenav .action-object {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.sidenav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 120;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /*padding-top: 60px;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.sideNavCaseCode {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>-->
  <h1 class="sideNavCaseCode">Case Code</h1>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="home" onclick="closeNav()">Home</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="search" onclick="closeNav()">Search</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="evidence" onclick="closeNav()">People</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="people" onclick="closeNav()">Evidence</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="tools" onclick="closeNav()">Tools</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="questions" onclick="closeNav()">Questions</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the replies i managed to get it working by using position absolute, top: 0 and right: 0 with a 15px of right padding to get the result i was after:

[final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7iAq.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be missing parts of your html. My answer may be incomplete as I'll need to see the full structure of the page..

Still, if you want the `.sideNavCaseCode` to be in the right corner of your page. For that, you can do:

`.sideNavCaseCode { display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; }`

Let me know if this is of any help. If not, we'll try again!

Answer (score -1):

OP, here is an updated answer. If you want "Case Code" to always be at the top even when scrolling like in the small snippet then use `position: fixed` like I've shown with `.sideNavCaseCode2`

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { margin: 0 } h1 { margin: 0 }

.sidenav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.sideNavCaseCode {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 15px 15px auto auto;
}
.sideNavCaseCode2 {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 15px auto auto 15px;
}

.action-object {
  color: currentColor;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <!--<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>-->
  <h1 class="sideNavCaseCode">Case Code</h1>
  <h1 class="sideNavCaseCode2">Fixed Postion</h1>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="home" onclick="closeNav()">Home</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="search" onclick="closeNav()">Search</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="evidence" onclick="closeNav()">People</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="people" onclick="closeNav()">Evidence</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="tools" onclick="closeNav()">Tools</button>
  <button class="action-object" data-action="goto" data-info="questions" onclick="closeNav()">Questions</button>
</div>
```