Position an item vertically to the top in its parent container
Following a guide on flex items, I have understood is as you can use "align-self" on a item to set its specific position inside its flex container. So in my case of trying to get the item to stay at the top of its container, I have used
align-self: flex-start;

However when I use this option it applies horizontally and not vertically. I have set my flex container to use:
flex-direction: column;

To have the other items centered, I have set the flex container to use:
justify-content: center;

Overall my code looks like this:
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}

.top-container {
   align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}

.center-container {
  background-color: green;
  
}

I have tried this in a clean environment, so there is not any extra css or something that are overriding. All the code I'm using is what I have showed here. Any help would be appreciated.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455207/how-do-i-get-a-flexbox-to-have-a-center-fixed-and-a-bottom-fixed-children-togeth

@Paulie_D Thanks for the suggestion. I have looked at the former question, but I can't see how it could be applied to get the item to the top, only to the bottom.

Essentially the same problem, you just have to adapt it to your issue.

Create snippet?

@Paulie_D Yes, I do understand you can set it to an absolute position, setting top to "0". What I hoped for was to learn how to use align-self correct, but maybe it only works horizontally.

There are other options than position in that link... consider those.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties

@Paulie_D  I will. And thank you for the link! I was hoping to find a more "correct" way to use the flex system. Essestially finding out how to use "align-self" in the combination of "flex-direction" of the type "column". The solutions in the link looks like workarounds, at least to me :)
Edit: Just saw the other link you provided. Thank you very much, it looks like a great continuation for my research on the flex system.

Use .center-container { margin: auto 0; }:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: dashed 2px red;
  padding: 12px;
  gap: 12px;
}

.top-container {
  padding: 12px;
  border: dashed 2px blue;
}

.center-container {
  padding: 12px;
  border: dashed 2px green;
  margin: auto 0;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top-container">top-container</div>
  <div class="center-container">center-container</div>
</div>



